# Filtering using If Function in R Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shinydashboard

I wanted to add a two-layer filter using the if function, because I find that I wasn't able to do much of the table manipulations (i.e. adding an additional aggregation row to have the calculation done, changing column names, getting rid of repetitive words in certain columns, etc) inside the server function. In other words, I have one master table `df`, in which the table `df1` is the cleaned version of `df`, and `df2` and `df3` are subsets of the master dataframe. However, I have to add an additional aggregation row at the end of each displayed dataframe. The code for the dataframes are as follows:

```
df<- data.frame(c("Apple","Orange","Pear","Pear"),c(6.99,4.99,6.99,4.99),c("Yes","No","Yes","Maybe"),c(5,5,2,5))
df1<- data.frame(c("Apple","Orange","Pear",""),c(6.99,4.99,6.99,4.99),c("Yes","No","Yes","Maybe"),c(5,5,2,5))
df2<- data.frame(c("Apple","Orange"),c(6.99,4.99),c("Yes","No"),c(5,5))
df3<- data.frame(c("Pear",""),c(6.99,4.99),c("Yes","Maybe"),c(2,5))

colnames(df1)<-c("ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD")
colnames(df2)<-c("ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD")
colnames(df3)<-c("ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD")
colnames(df)<-c("ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD")

#saving the df
df02<- df2
df03 <- df3

#aggregate row
df1[dim(df1)[1]+1,3]<- "Average Score"
df1[dim(df1)[1],4]<- mean(df1$ColD,na.rm = TRUE)
df2[dim(df2)[1]+1,3]<- "Average Score"
df2[dim(df2)[1],4]<- mean(df2$ColD,na.rm = TRUE)
df3[dim(df3)[1]+1,3]<- "Average Score"
df3[dim(df3)[1],4]<- mean(df3$ColD,na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, when I tried to add a second layer of filtering using the IF function in the renderTable Output, the second layer of filtering and aggregation doesn't work.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Test"),

  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Data Table", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("th")))),

  dashboardBody(tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
        fluidRow( 
          box(
              radioButtons(inputId="filter1", label="Types", choiceNames = c("All","Not Pear","Pear"), choiceValues = c("df1","df2","df3"),inline= TRUE),
              radioButtons(inputId="filter2", label="Verify", choices = c("All","Yes","No","Maybe"),inline= TRUE))),
        fluidRow(box(
              column(8, align="center", offset = 2,tags$b(textOutput("text1"))),

              br(),br(),br(),br(),
              textOutput("text2"),
              tableOutput("static1"),
              width=12))

      )))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text1 <- renderText({ "This Table" })
  output$text2 <- renderText({"PR"})
  df02 <- reactive({
    get(input$filter1)
  })
  output$static1 <- renderTable({if (input$filter2 == "All"){
    df02() #if the second filter is All, that means that we don't filter and just return the first filter's tables
  }
    else {
    df4<-subset(subset(df, ColC == input$filter2),ColA == input$filter1)
    df4[dim(df4)[1]+1,3]<- "Average Score"
    df4[dim(df4)[1],4]<- mean(df4$ColD,na.rm = TRUE)
    reactive({df4})()
    }
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to fix my Table Output?

**EDIT**

I did this for `output$static1` and it still doesn't work for the second layer of the All and the Pear filter

```
output$static1 <- renderTable({if (input$filter2 == "All"){
    df02() #if the second filter is All, that means that we don't filter and just return the first filter's tables
  }
    else if (input$filter1 == "Pear" && input$filter2 != "All") {
    df4<-subset(subset(df, ColC == input$filter2), ColA == "Pear")
    df4[dim(df4)[1]+1,3]<- "Average Score"
    df4[dim(df4)[1],4]<- mean(df4$ColD,na.rm = TRUE)
    reactive({df4})()
    }
    else if (input$filter1 == "All" && input$filter2 != "All") {
    df4<-subset(df, ColC == input$filter2)
    df4[dim(df4)[1]+1,3]<- "Average Score"
    df4[dim(df4)[1],4]<- mean(df4$ColD,na.rm = TRUE)
    reactive({df4})()
    }
    else {
    df4<-subset(df, ColC == input$filter2)
    df4 <- subset(df4, ColA != "Pear")
    df4[dim(df4)[1]+1,3]<- "Average Score"
    df4[dim(df4)[1],4]<- mean(df4$ColD,na.rm = TRUE)
    reactive({df4})()
    }
    
    })
```

Comment: That is because your `ColA` has values `c("Apple","Orange","Pear")`, but you are trying to subset with `ColA == input$filter1`, which results in no matching values as `filter1` has `c("df1","df2","df3")` as possible values.

Comment: Thank you, I've posted an edit to show my problems still exist even if I did the if function detailing everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Test"),

  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data Table", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("th")))),

  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    # First tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
            fluidRow(
              box(
                radioButtons(inputId="filter1", label="Types", choiceNames = c("All","Not Pear","Pear"), choiceValues = c("All","NotPear","Pear"),inline= TRUE),
                radioButtons(inputId="filter2", label="Verify", choices = c("All","Yes","No","Maybe"),inline= TRUE))),
            fluidRow(box(
              column(8, align="center", offset = 2,tags$b(textOutput("text1"))),

              br(),br(),br(),br(),
              textOutput("text2"),
              tableOutput("static1"),
              width=12))

    )))
)
#choiceValues = c("df1","df2","df3")

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text1 <- renderText({ "This Table" })
  output$text2 <- renderText({"PR"})
  dfa <- reactive({
    if (input$filter1 == "All"){
      df1
    }else{
      if (input$filter1 == "Pear") { choices = c("Pear","")
      }else choices = c("Apple","Orange")
      df1 %>% dplyr::filter(ColA %in% choices)
    }
  })

  dff <- reactive({
    if (input$filter2 == "All"){
      df4 <- dfa() #if the second filter is All, that means that we don't filter and just return the first filter's tables
    }
    else {
      if (input$filter1 == "All"){ choices = c("Apple","Orange","Pear","")
      }else if (input$filter1 == "Pear") { choices = c("Pear","")
      }else choices = c("Apple","Orange")
      df4 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(ColC == input$filter2, ColA %in% choices)
      df4[dim(df4)[1]+1,3]<- "Average Score"
      df4[dim(df4)[1],4]<- mean(df4$ColD,na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    df4
  })
  
  output$static1 <- renderTable({ dff() })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I got what I needed from the if-else logic presented, though I have to say that I changed ```dfa``` to ```dfa <- reactive({
    if (input$filter1 == "All"){
      df1
    }else{
      if (input$filter1 == "Pear") { df3)
      }else choices = c("Apple","Orange")
      df2
    }
  })``` The aggregate row at the end didn't show up when the Verify filter is at "All" and the Types filter is at either Pear/Not Pear.

Comment: Please see my comment below your question.